# Play Scala 2.4 linking asynchronous calls

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to figure out how to link multiple asynchronous calls and return a result. I am currently trying to asynchronously user data first, and update user data asynchronously and return result, but it seems like it is not working :(
i used map { result => Ok(result)}, but play still thinks that I am returning an object. any help?

```
def updateUserData() = Action.async { implicit request =>
updateUserForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
errors => Future.successful(BadRequest(views.html.authenticated.settings.settings_hero(errors, Option(""), Option("")))),
{
  case (userData) =>
    request.session.get("email") match {
      case Some(email) =>
        getUser(email, userData.curent_password) map { userCheck =>
          if (userCheck) {
            updateUserOnService(email, userData.f_name, userData.l_name, userData.new_password) map { result =>
              Ok("please")
            }
            //val e = updateUserOnService(email, userData.f_name, userData.l_name, userData.new_password) map {result => Ok("")}

            // user is valid now update the user data

            // call removeAuth to log out

            // redirect to home
            ///Ok (updateUserOnService(email, userData.f_name, userData.l_name, userData.new_password) map { result => result})
            //Redirect(routes.settings.index()).addingToSession("email" -> email)
          } else {
            BadRequest(views.html.authenticated.settings.settings_hero(updateUserForm.bindFromRequest.withGlobalError(Messages("error.login", email)), Option(""), Option("")))
          }
        }
      }
  })
}
```

The main part that i am having issue is this part. I think it is matter of some syntax. Could someone help?
Thanks

```
updateUserOnService(email, userData.f_name, userData.l_name, userData.new_password) map { result =>
  Ok("please")
}
```

Comment: Can you share the method signatures (more specifically the return types) of: `getUser` and `updateUserOnService`. Without it it's hard for us to infer the types in our heads :)

Comment: def updateUserOnService(email: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, n_password: String) = {
    WS.url("http://localhost:9000/settings/updateUser")
      .post(Map("email" -> Seq(email), "firstName" -> Seq(firstName), "lastName" -> Seq(lastName), "n_password" -> Seq(n_password)))
  }

Comment: def getUser(email: String, password: String) = {
    WS.url("http://localhost:81/authenticateUser")
      .post(Map("email" -> Seq(email), "password" -> Seq(password)))
      .map(response => response.body.contains("true"))
  }

Comment: I am sorry I am kinda new to stack, so I dont know how to edit or re-format the code so that it is easier for you guys to see :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with your types and that they don't match up with the required ones.

`.fold` has to result in `Future[Result]` in both branches (the error and the success ones).

In the successful form bind branch you have this:

```
case (userData) => ... // The ... must evaluate to Future[Result]
```

Looking at your first operation we see:

```
request.session.get("email") match {
  case Some(email) => ...
}
```

One big issue here is that the `None` case is not handled! (but this is does not cause the types not matching up). Having something like the following will solve this: `case None => Future.successful(BadRequest(...))`

So moving on: in the `Some` you have the following:

```
getUser(email, userData.curent_password) map { userCheck =>
  if (userCheck) {
    updateUserOnService(email, userData.f_name, userData.l_name, userData.new_password) map { result =>
       Ok("please")
    }
  } else {
    BadRequest(views.html.authenticated.settings.settings_hero(updateUserForm.bindFromRequest.withGlobalError(Messages("error.login", email)), Option(""), Option("")))
  }
}
```

This is where the issue is:

`getUser` will return with a `Future[X]` and when you map over it you will have `Future[Y]` where `Y` will be what `userCheck => ...` evaluates to.

In this case the types are totally mixed up, since when you do `if(usercheck)` on the true branch you have `Future[Result]` on the false branch you have `Result`. So the types don't align on both branches which is a big issue and the compiler will infer `Any` from this.

To fix this, in the false branch create a future: `Future.successful(BadRequest(....))`

Ok, now that we fixed the most inner type issues, let's start going backwards. Inside we have `Future[Result]`, if we go back one level (before the `getUser()`) then we will have `Future[Future[Result]]`. Again this is not what we want, because we need `Future[Result]`.

The solution to this is to `flatMap` instead of `map`, because with `flatMap` when you need to return with the same container type and it flattens it. A quick example to understand this:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3).flatMap(i => Seq(i, i))
// res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
```

In the case of `Future`s:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future   
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
Future(1).flatMap(i => Future(i*2))
// res1: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = [....]
```

So we see that we don't have double nesting, but just a single `Future`.

Going back to your example this would be my updated code that would work better:

```
def updateUserData() = Action.async { implicit request =>
  updateUserForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    errors => Future.successful(BadRequest(views.html.authenticated.settings.settings_hero(errors, Option(""), Option("")))),
    {
      case (userData) =>
        request.session.get("email") match {
          case Some(email) =>
            getUser(email, userData.curent_password).flatMap { userCheck =>
              if (userCheck) {
                updateUserOnService(email, userData.f_name, userData.l_name, userData.new_password) map { result =>
                  Ok("please")
                }
              } else {
                Future.successful(BadRequest(views.html.authenticated.settings.settings_hero(updateUserForm.bindFromRequest.withGlobalError(Messages("error.login", email)), Option(""), Option(""))))
              }
            }
        case None => Future.successful(BadRequest) // FIXME: Implement as you wish
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! I can't upvote yours because I do not have enough reputation :( It does work right now! I knew the type was the problem :(

Comment: @ShawnYoon If you found that this answers the question then please mark it as answered with the green checkmark.